# Is it possible to show push notification as popup message in android?

Tags: android

I want push notification as popup message .I dont want to show it top of the status bar . when ever push notification arrives  .Please help me!!

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't do that. It's annoying.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, **i think you shouldn't do it**, the notification patter is perfect to not be too much intrusive to the User UX.

But if you realy want to do it you can't do it with a common [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) cause you won't have any reference to an activity.

So what you can do is to start an Activity with [Theme.Holo.Dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_Holo_Dialog) set as style.

Start the activity like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, YourActivityClass.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thank for replay Mario Lenci

Answer (score 2):

You can, through every `Dialog` classes available in Android. For more information, [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) should help you.

However, Google did design for Android a notification bar and a [Notification API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) probably because they would like you to use it. Using `Dialogs` causes bad and interrupted user experience. Moreover, there are several other technical advantages of using Notifications over `Dialogs` :

- Showing `Dialogs` pauses your activity in the background, a notification doesn't.
- Notifications can be posted in the background, a `Dialog` hardly can be

I would advise you to use `Notifications` whenever you need to advertise the user of an asynchronous event he might be interested in. I would then recommend using `Dialogs` as text inputs (credentials for instance) or whenever you need to prompt the user to make an explicit decision.